# I am not able to create foreign key in mysql Error 150. Please help

Tags: sql, database, mysql

i am trying to create a foreign key in my table. But when i executes my query it shows me error 150.

```
Error Code : 1025
Error on create foreign key of '.\vts\#sql-6ec_1' to '.\vts\tblguardian' (errno: 150)
(0 ms taken)
```

My Queries are

Query to create a foreign Key

```
alter table `vts`.`tblguardian` add constraint `FK_tblguardian` FOREIGN KEY (`GuardianPickPointId`) REFERENCES `tblpickpoint` (`PickPointId`)
```

Primary Key table

```
CREATE TABLE `tblpickpoint` (                                                           
                `PickPointId` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,                                         
                `PickPointName` varchar(500) default NULL,                                            
                `PickPointLabel` varchar(500) default NULL,                                           
                `PickPointLatLong` varchar(100) NOT NULL,                                             
                PRIMARY KEY  (`PickPointId`)                                                          
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Foreign Key Table

```
CREATE TABLE `tblguardian` (                           
               `GuardianId` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,         
               `GuardianName` varchar(500) default NULL,            
               `GuardianAddress` varchar(500) default NULL,         
               `GuardianMobilePrimary` varchar(15) NOT NULL,        
               `GuardianMobileSecondary` varchar(15) default NULL,  
               `GuardianPickPointId` int(4) default NULL,     
               PRIMARY KEY  (`GuardianId`)                          
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta: You should create a new question instead of changing your old question. In your new question do link back to your original question if it provides useful background information. When you change a question to a different one, the existing answers no longer make sense and so it becomes useless to other people with the same problem who find this site via Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the type of the columns in your constraint are different. They must be the same.

```
`PickPointId` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment, 

`GuardianPickPointId` varchar(100) default NULL,
```

For more information see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar internal data types inside InnoDB so that they can be compared without a type conversion. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this step by step issue list

[MySQL Error Number 1005 Can’t create table ‘.\mydb#sql-328_45.frm’ (errno: 150)](http://www.verysimple.com/blog/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/)